# Format an editable textarea

Tags: java, swing, format

At the moment I try to find a method to create a TextArea that I can edit and simply (without cheating) apply syntax highlighting to. Is that possible without the need of a custom Component? I already managed to format a text using a JEditorPane, but I am not sure how to implement that the text is dynamicly highlighted... And that efficiently. Is that possibly without an enormous amount of coding?

Comment: You could take a look at something like [rsyntaxtarea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) for ideas

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a JTextArea since it does not support text attributes.

Instead you can use a `JTextPane`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: I knew that with the JTextPane, but your link helped me a lot - thanks for that!